# Weird display on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, display, desktop-icons, visual-artifacts

[image: wonky grid of squarish uneven green dots appear over desktop background]

I have installed i3wn with gaps on my device. This is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. When I log in with Ubuntu it is showing like this, whereas when I log in with i3wn everything is fine.

Also, possibly relatedly, I can't update my system, it is showing an error:

> Package dependencies cannot be resolved...

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of `apt policy libegl-mesa0` Please do not edit in a new picture, copy and paste the output as text.